# Increase value of session variable for each call to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Each time a click on a link in the `View` and call an `ActionResult` method in the `Controller`, I need to increase the value of the `session` variable, but it's not working.

When I start the value is 17 and when I click on the link and pass 1 to the `Controller` I want the result to be 18 and next time I click it should be 19.

But what have I done wrong and how can I improve the code? The value is a nullable int in the `ActionResult`.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? value) {

        // Session
        if (Session["week"] == null)
        {
            // Create session
            Session["week"] = week.WeekNum();
        }

        if (!value.HasValue)
        {
            weekStart = (int)Session["week"];
        }
        else
        {
            Session["week"] = + value;
            weekStart = (int)Session["week"];
        }

        ViewBag.weekNumber = weekStart;

        ... the rest of the code...
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it's not working.`?

Comment: @JasonEvans It's not increasing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest writing a helper function to do the increment e.g.

```
private void IncrementWeeks(int weeks)
{
    if (Session["week"] == null)
    {
        Session["week"] = week.WeekNum();
        return;
    }

    int currentWeek = 0;

    if (int.TryParse(Session["week"].ToString(), out currentWeek))
    {
        Session["week"] = (currentWeek + weeks).ToString();
    }
}
```

Just to cover `NULL` checking and `int` conversion issues.

Here's how you could wrap getting the value from the session into a helper function too:

```
private int ReadWeekFromSession()
{
    if (Session["week"] == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int currentWeek = 0;

    if (int.TryParse(Session["week"].ToString(), out currentWeek))
    {
    }

    return currentWeek;
}
```

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? value)
{
    int weekStart = 0;

    if (!value.HasValue)
    {
        weekStart = ReadWeekFromSession();
    }
    else
    {
        IncrementWeeks(value.Value);
        weekStart = ReadWeekFromSession();
    }

    // Rest of controller code....    
}
```

Comment: Hopefully it will suite your needs. You might have to tweak it to fit your requirements, but it should serve as a good starting point for you.

Comment: When I run for the first time and after I have erased the session, shouldn't the current week be set to the current week?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. If you erase the session, then Session["week"] will be `NULL` (if that is what you mean by `erasing`).

Comment: I just meant that first time I run the result it's 0

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your answer was very detailed! Just wonder why toString is used since it's all about int values and what role does "out" have in the two code bocks?

Comment: `int.TryParse()` expects a `string` as the first parameter. Calling `Session["week"]` returns an `object`. So you must call `.ToString()` to convert that object to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You'd increment the value just like you would from any other data source:

1. Retrieve the value
2. Modify the value
3. Store the new value

Which could be something as simple as:

```
var weekValue = int.Parse(Session["week"].ToString());
weekValue += value;
Session["week"] = weekValue;
```

If it's possible that the session variable isn't a valid integer, you might use `int.TryParse()` instead or some other means of checking for that condition.

Or to avoid using that `.ToString()` call, if the potential for errors with the value is small enough to use `int.Parse()` in the first place then I suppose you could get away with this as well:

```
var weekValue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["week"]);
```

Which is a bit more forgiving on the input types, since it has *many* overloads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to be some kind of problem. I get a red line below this code ...(Session["week"]); and the error message is "cannot convert from object to string" ? I also got a red line below the second row, but when I added (int) before value it disappeared.

Comment: @3D-kreativ: If the error potential for formatting is low, then you can use `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.Parse()`.  To use the latter I suppose appending a `.ToString()` to the session value would technically do the trick.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: I thought this would be quite easy to solve, it's the second row that don't work after I added the (int) in front of "value". Error message: Nullable object must have a value and without the (int) in front of "value" the error is : cannot implicitly convert type int? to int

Comment: @3D-kreativ: If you've already checked the `.HasValue` property (which it looks like you have), then you can use `+= value.Value` safely.

Comment: @3D-kreativ: What do you mean?  You should keep whatever code you need in order to perform the logic you're looking to perform.